# How do you re-enable a jQuery tab after you consumed the 'onclick'?

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, onclick

This might be a newbie question... but here goes...

I set up some tabs using jQuery:

```
<div id='tabs'>
   <ul id='ui-tab-ul'>
      <li><a href='#tabPrimaryDetail'>Primary</a></li>
      <li><a href='#tabSecondaryDetail' onclick='javascript: jQuery.fn.getSecondaryDetails();'>Secondary</a></li>                   
   </ul>
   <div id='tabPrimaryDetail'>
       <p>No information available</p>
   </div>
   <div id='tabSecondaryDetail'>
       <p>No information available</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

The content of my Primary panel is generated from some other mouse click, but since it is the first tab, i didn't need to activate the tab itself... But for my secondary tab, I want to get its content when people click on the tab itself... So i put an onclick event there to perform an AJAX call, get the data, and filled the content...

However, I can't show the secondary tab... I tried using:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('show', 1);
```

or

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
```

But none of them work, if i use select, it would simply trigger my custom AJAX call again... Is there a way to preserve the onclick for the tab action?

Sorry, I'm still fairly new with jQuery, only start getting to use it for about 2 weeks.

Comment: an event has no `javascript:`
just attribute href has `javascript:`

Answer (score 0):

You're either not showing A LOT of code, or it's full of errors.
First, I don't see '#tabs' defined anywhere:

```
<div id="tabs">
```

for example... Then, do show a certain element, you can use [.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function. Like this:

```
$('#tabSecondaryDetail').show();
```

Also, this:

```
onclick='javascript: jQuery.fn.getSecondaryDetails();'
```

should be:

```
onclick='getSecondaryDetails();'
```

etc...

I don't want to give you the full code now, but I hope this is a good start.

Comment: stackoverflow was messed up after i edited it... looks like I need an extra linebrake if i want to post the code.

Comment: Could you please explain why I don't need to put a full function call such as jQuery.fn.<my function>()? Because I just tried your method, and it can't find my function...

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using plain jQuery (in which case you should call functions the way I wrote), but obviously you're also using a jQuery UI plugin (like @GregM pointed out), so you should probably keep it the old way. Just try to include more info about the question next time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be not to use the onclick on the `a` tag

Maybe you should use another event more like show or select

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { jQuery.fn.getSecondaryDetails();}
});
```

to Fill the tab before it get showed

Or

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
   show: function(event, ui) { jQuery.fn.getSecondaryDetails();}
});
```

to Fill the tab after it get showed

Comment: This won't do a thing for many reasons, one is that #tabs doesn't exist. Second, onclick event is okay on the a tags, you just need to return false or preventDefault() behavior.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he as the tabs id if he is using this : http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-show, and why using onclick when he can use the defaul event of the library he is using

Comment: Definitely! Still, he should've shown the container div, right?

Comment: yeah sure, we do as we can when we don't have all the code :)